# How can I make git understand the shortest unique abbreviation for a command?

Tags: git

How can I configure git to recognise the shortest unique prefix of a command, like git does with SHA hashes, or like mercurial does?

e.g. `git ad` should be recognised as `git add`, or `git conf` as `git config`.

Clearly I could do this by adding a bunch of aliases, but that's far too brittle in the face of new commands, and tedious too.

Is there some built in functionality for doing this, or a plugin?

I've already got satisfactory text editor integration, and I'm not interested in aliases.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you don't want to add aliases, then the best approach that comes to my mind is just pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> after the command. In example:

- `git con` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> will result in `git config`.
- `git com` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> will result in `git commit`.
- `git ad` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> will result in `git add`.
- etc.

PS: no, there is not such build-in functionality.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are asking for a new feature. Git is open sourced, so you can enhance it anyway you want:

https://github.com/git/git

You can pull the source code. I see that the commands are defined under an array named commands[] inside git.c. And matching appears to be done inside the following function:

```
static struct cmd_struct *get_builtin(const char *s)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(commands); i++) {
            struct cmd_struct *p = commands + i;
            if (!strcmp(s, p->cmd))
                    return p;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

You can modify the line of strcmp() to do your minimum prefix match. I think it should not take more than 20 lines of code.

Comment: Is there an existing feature request to comment?  I would hope it would be more general, supporting sub-commands like `git stash l` for list.  It could be enabled by an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fine article on creating aliases for git commands.

http://githowto.com/aliases

Also, your editor of choice may have built in git integration. Here's an example with sublime. I don't believe there are any plugins to modify git's built in command structure.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-git-inside-of-sublime-text-to-improve-workflow

Answer (score -1):

"in the face of new commands" — which new commands? In my opinion, that doesn't happen very often, and even then, it's likely not a command you're going to use often.

I'd recommend using Zsh with the [`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) Git plugin. It offers [lots of useful aliases](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh).

Of course, you could also just copypaste the aliases and use them in Bash, but you'd lose the nice auto-completion features. Also you'd have to make sure to define the helper functions as well.